# Cannot unzip .7z files to google colab

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I'm trying to work with Kaggle's Corporacion Favorita grocery dataset, I have uploaded the dataset to kaggle but cannot seem to unzip it. Why is it saying cannot read? The files are the in appropriate directory.
[image: My code where I'm trying to unzip a .7z file]

Comment: `~/content` is not `/content` :)

Comment: what should I do then? which directory is the correct one?

Comment: Well, if your cwd is `/content` and holds the `train.csv.7z` you should `p7zip -d /content/train.csv.7z` without the snake `~`

Comment: did that, its still giving the same error.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -la /content`?

Comment: total 16
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 21 16:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Dec  1 19:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 21 16:30 .config
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 21 16:30 sample_data

I  guess its justs sample_data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203436/discussion-between-m02ph3u5-and-husun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your file `train.csv.7z` is stored inside `/content` but you try to uncompress `~/content/train.csv.7z` which evaluates to `/root/content/train.csv.7z` for you seem to be the root user and `~` gets evaluated to the user's home directory.

Try:

```sh
!p7zip -d /content/train.csv.7z
```

---

Maybe `os.getcwd()` will not be the same as `!pwd`. When `!ls` shows the file it seems to be in your cwd.

Try:

```
!p7zip -d train.csv.7z
```